# what happens when we shut down the nodes of a private ethereum network?

Tags: private-blockchain, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, nodes

I created a private network using Microsoft-ethereum consortium template with 2 mining nodes and 1 transaction nodes on azure which are linux machines.

After a period of time I shut downed all the 3 nodes, started all the machines again.

After starting i started the ethereum node using start-private-blockchain.sh with geth.cfg and password.

Node started sucessfully.

Now when I try to access my previously created contracts with the previous address availble I am not able to access the contract?

What is the issue here?  Is the data about the contract lost when the machines are shut downed or the mining nodes are not connected to the transaction nodes during the node initialization?

Or is it entirely different issue? I didn't do any thing specifically for associating mining nodes when starting my private network.

Comment: Check from geth logs that all the nodes are synching and in the same block number

Comment: can u pls be elaborate how to check.. i am very much new to this..when i opened the log "geth.log" i didnt find any record abt nodes.

Comment: geth persistently stores all blocks on the disk. It may be the case that some nodes do not have access to others hence mined blocks are not propagated.

Comment: how to check access and make every thing normal again?

Answer (score 1):

If the contract transaction was mined correctly, and your chain is fully synced then the contract will be on the blockchain at a particular address.

In the geth console you can type `eth.blockNumber` to see the current block that your node has synced. If this is lower than the 'Best block' linked on [EthStats.net](https://ethstats.net/) then you are not fully synced.

Comment: I am running a private block chain ? how to find best block in this case? If found not in sync how to sync ?

Comment: After browsing i cam to know how to find peers ? by net.peerCount and admin.peers .. both are returning zero and empty array.? does the peer mean the mining node ?